# PE file section RVA calculation

Tags: windows, filesystems, reverse-engineering, portable-executable

I'm currently looking through a PE file's section table, both from the raw data on the disk, and through a couple of PE analysers.  I'm a little confused over how some addresses are being interpreted.

For example.  From the raw PE image on disk, I see this:

```
.text    virtualSize: 0x1A0F71  virtualAddress: 0x1000  rawSize: 0x1A1000
```

However, when using some PE analysers (LordPE, pedump.me), I see this:

```
.text    virtualSize: 0x114d41  virtualAddress: 0x1000  rawSize: 0x114e00
```

I'm not sure how these values are being interpreted.  It is something to do with alignment, and the image's base address?

Any input would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This requires psychic debugging, the size of a section isn't affected by RVA.  The crystal ball says that you are actually looking at two *different* files.  And your PE dumper utilities are 32-bit programs that you run on a 64-bit operating system.

You have to understand the [File System Redirector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  A 32-bit process will be redirected from c:\windows\system32 to c:\windows\syswow64 and from c:\program files to c:\program files (x86).  So your PE dumper utilities could well be opening the 32-bit version of an executable instead.  And yes, the .text section will be substantially smaller.

Copy the file to a directory that's not affected by redirection, like your Documents folder.

Comment: Thanks Hans!  I had a funny feeling something like this was happening.  I've just done some more testing and my program is doing exactly what it should be.  The differences in values were what was confusing me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Maybe [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tb1dM.jpg) would help you to solve the problem:
[image]

Comment: Thanks Damian.  I already have a copy of that, but I'm still a little confused. I think I'm overlooking something obvious!